# for loop not working correctly with jquery ajax function phonegap ligntbox

Tags: jquery, loops, asynchronous, cordova, lightbox

hi im working in Phonegap v2.9.0 and Jquerymobile v1.3.2 and im using xcode v5 editor. i'm using this [Photo lightbox](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/popup/index.html) to show images as lightbox. i have also tried photoswipe but i think problem is async ajax in loop. 
I want to load photos from webservice. For this i have to load albums. Albums are loading fine. When i click that specific album list of photo links are loaded and save in array.I have to loop each link to get each photo for that album everything is working fine except for lightbox. When i copy log of ( console.log('liGallery complete==' + aGallery);) contents of divgallery in another page they are working fine but not in the page where i want to show them. 

 Here is my code

```
window.LoadphotosView = function(){
    try{
        var  aGallery = "";

        var ItemsCount=photolink_arr.length;
        var divGallery = document.getElementById("Gallery"); 
        var X_CSRFToken = sessionStorage.getItem('X_CSRFToken');
        var cookies='SUID=' + X_CSRFToken;

        console.log('LoadphotosView function');
        console.log('photolink_arr=' + photolink_arr[0]); 
        console.log('photolink_arr.length=' + ItemsCount);

        if(ItemsCount==0 || ItemsCount =='undefined' || ItemsCount==''){
            divGallery.innerHTML = 'No photo found';
            return;
        }

        for (var i=0; i <  ItemsCount; i++)
        {  
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                ajaxcounter: i,
                async: false, 
                url: photolink_arr[i],
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/vnd.domain.collection+json; charset=utf8",
                headers: {Cookie: cookies},
                success: function (data){  
                    var photo= data.image_link;
                    var thumbphoto= data.thumbnail_link;  
                    console.log('counter=' + this.ajaxcounter); 
                    console.log("stringify photolink_arr=" + JSON.stringify(data));
                    console.log("data.items.photo_link=" + data.image_link); 
                    console.log('photo==' + photo);
                    console.log('thumbphoto==' + thumbphoto);  

                    aGallery += ' <a href="#popupPhoto' + i + '" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade"><img class="popphoto" src="' + thumbphoto + '" alt="Thumb Photos" style="width:200px;height:200px;padding:5px;"></a>   <div data-role="popup" id="popupPhoto' + i + '" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="d" data-position-to="window" data-corners="false"> <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a><img class="popphoto" src="' + photo + '" style="max-height:512px;" alt="Photos"> </div>'; 


                    if(this.ajaxcounter==ItemsCount-1){ 
                         console.log('liGallery complete==' + aGallery);
                        divGallery.innerHTML= aGallery ;
                    }
                },
                complete: function() {                    
                    console.log ('LoadphotosView function complete');                    
                },            
                error: function (request,data)
                { 
                    alert("load albums error request=" + JSON.stringify( request)); 
                }
            }) ; 
        }  
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

html code

```
   <div id="Gallery" data-role="content" class="gallery">
       <div style='font-size:14pt;color:#fff;'>Loading..</div>
    </div>
```

please help me to how images as lightbox in Jquerymobile, Phonegap

Comment: What type of device are you testing on? Do you have any log information from the browser on that page indicating a problem? Since you can get the images, I assume you correctly added the server to your whitelist. It sounds like there is just a javascript issue.

Comment: i have tested on simulator and iphone 4s. When carefully read the log due to async in nature the concatenation is done before ajax load data. So i coded these lines if(this.ajaxcounter==ItemsCount-1){ 
                         console.log('liGallery complete==' + aGallery);
                        divGallery.innerHTML= aGallery ;
                    } when i  copy log of aGallery into  div Gallery manually then everything works fine